# Como abrir proyecto en Cmder laragon?

Tags: cmd

me encuentro aprendiendo laravel y estoy usando laragon como entorno de desarrollo.
Voy al grano tengo mi proyecto ya creado que se encuentra en laragon/www/recetas, mi pregunta es como puede abrirlo en Cmder para utilizar comandos para crear controladores y autenticacion(esto es lo que mas me interesa), etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: trata ejecutando `cd recetas`

Comment: Muchas gracias! seguro es una tontería lo que estoy preguntando pero soy nuevo con este framework.

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Laravel si no con como moverte entre carpetas desde el símbolo del sistema, te recomiendo leas de eso